# Coloring consecutive bars with different colors

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to color different consecutive bars, outside of a volatility band, with different colors. Example:

Standard Keltner channels. I'm looking for a candle that is completely outside of the band (`low >= upKeltnerBand`), and then I want to color only the first candle with a color. (`barcolor(upFreeBar ? color.green : na, title="Free Bar")`

Obviously doing it this way, makes all bars that a freely standing green. I couldn't figure out how to "group" certain candles, so that I can apply a different color to them. I don't understand how that is done logically.

For example, I could do:

```
upFreebar = low[4] >= upKeltnerBand[4] and low[3] >= upKeltnerBand[3] and low[2] >= upKeltnerBand[2] and etc.
```

But that doesn't work. Also, I know that in some languages there's a shortcut for grouping parts of an array together, e.g. low[4:1], but that doesn't seem to work in PineScript. Is that correct?

Let's say I'd want to group the first free bar through the third with one color, and then the fourth bar through the eighth with a different color. I hope this is somewhat understandable. Thank you.

Code snippet:

```
atrlength = 14

// Keltner bands
downKeltnerBand = ( ema(close, 21) - (rma(tr(true), atrlength) * 2) )
upKeltnerBand = ( ema(close, 21) + (rma(tr(true), atrlength) * 2) )

firstFreeBar = low >= upKeltnerBand
barcolor(firstFreeBar ? color.green : na, title="First Free Bar")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three bars above the channel are orange, and from the fourth bar onwards are blue.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Keltner)", overlay=true)
atrlength = 14

// Keltner bands
downKeltnerBand = ( ema(close, 21) - (rma(tr(true), atrlength) * 2) )
upKeltnerBand = ( ema(close, 21) + (rma(tr(true), atrlength) * 2) )

plot(downKeltnerBand)
plot(upKeltnerBand)

firstFreeBar = low < upKeltnerBand
numFreeBar = barssince(firstFreeBar)

color color_bar = na

if numFreeBar > 3
    color_bar := color.blue
else if numFreeBar > 0
    color_bar := color.orange
else
    color_bar := na
    
//barcolor(firstFreeBar ? color.blue : na, title="First Free Bar")
barcolor(color_bar, title="First Free Bar")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solves it although you have the comparison the other way around like I had, which had me confused for a while. But now I know what that `barssince` function is used for. :)